# Spinner with hint above selected element's string

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner, custom-adapter

I want to realize a Spinner with a "TextView with a hint", I already tried to pass another view beside R.layout.simple_spinner_item to the ArrayAdapter, but it doesn't work.

I want to do this by editing the Spinner element, not using a layout containing the TextView and the Spinner, how could i do it? I don't know how to realize a CustomAdapter, but, could that be the right way?

[image: Spinner Example]

EDIT: Uploaded image of the Spinner Example (I hope it isn't broken)

Comment: Can you attach a mock UI what you want to achieve. Its not clear what exactly you are trying to design.

Comment: You will have to make a custom adapter and override `getView()` for the selected item with a hint and `getDropDownView()` for the views that appear when you open the spinner up.